# TextView inside ScrollView not updated when padding changed

Tags: java, android, xml, textview, scrollview

I have a ScrollView defined in XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <CustomScrollView
        android:id="@+id/custom_scroll_view"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/edge_margin_x"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/edge_margin_x"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And I'm adding child views programmatically (this is inside CustomScrollView.java, which extends ScrollView):

```
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getContext());
    List<String> elements = ...;

    for (String value : elements) {
      TextView textView = new TextView(getContext());
      textView.setText(value);
      layout.addView(textView);
   }

   addView(layout);
```

Then, a bit later, I want to add padding to some of the TextViews:

```
textView.setPadding(100, 0, 100, 0);
```

The padding is set, but the TextView is just moving around since there is no refresh of the view. I tried invalidate()/requestLayout() but I cannot get everything to refresh. Where and on which elements should I call invalidate()/requestLayout()? Do I have some mistake in my XML?